# How do I put a zero in front of time using Cocoa-Touch?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Hello I am getting time from NSDate like this:

```
 NSDateComponents *hoursAndMinutes = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:feedItem.date];
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d", hoursAndMinutes.hour,hoursAndMinutes.minute];
```

But if the time from date is 13:05, it shows it like 13:5, and 09:17 like 9:17.

Thanks.

Comment: `%02d` would be the applicable standard printf format. There might something spiffier in iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateFormatter) will do what you are looking for.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:feedItem.date];

return formattedDate;
```

Comment: @DevFly See [Date Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) and follow links. "HH:mm" for 24-hour time it appears .. also perhaps a local phone setting?

Comment: for AM use 
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];

Answer (score 1):

Just use formatting:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", hoursAndMinutes.hour,hoursAndMinutes.minute];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try %02d instead of %d to force it to always display both digits. There are probably neater ways but this does seem to work.

Ref: http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/strings/displaying-values-in-strings

--EDIT--

Wow 3 answers in the space of 20 Seconds, I think @BJH has the neater solution.